# extract variables from python string template

Tags: python, django

For python string template is there a clean way to extract the variable names in the template string.

I actually want to to be able to write template stings into a textfield on and then substitue the variables for other more complex looking variables.

So for example I would get user inputted template into a variable

```
t = Template(( request.POST['comment'] ))
```

the comment string maybe

```
'$who likes $what'
```

I need an array of the variables names so I can convert the string to something like

```
{{{who}}} likes {{{what}}}
```

Maybe there is also a better way to approach this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def replaceVars(matchObj):
    return "{{{%s}}}" % matchObj.groups()[0]

c = r"\$(\w+)\s*"

s = "$who likes $what"

converted = re.sub(c, replaceVars, s)
```

Comment: This seems to be the best way right now. I am however struggling as I need to print the variable twice. It is more like {{{%s|something%s}}}

Comment: Like `{{{who|somethingwho}}}`, for example? Then just modify the replaceVars function.

Comment: cool - got it - just neede  % ( matchObj.groups()[0], matchObj.groups()[0])

Answer (score 3):

i don't know of any template-related api, but you can use a regexp:

```
>>> import re
>>> rx = re.compile(r'\$(\w+)')
>>> rx.sub(r'{{{\1}}}', '$who likes $what')
'{{{who}}} likes {{{what}}}'
```

the first argument to `rx.sub()` replaces each occurrence of a variable in the second argument, with `\1` being replaced by the name of the variable.